# Swift GCD: concurrent queue not working?

Tags: ios, swift, grand-central-dispatch

As I understand, in concurrent queue, former tasks won't block the execution of latter tasks. So how come only "hello" is printed but not a single "world" is printed in the following code?

```
override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()

    let concurrentQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "test", attributes: .concurrent)

    concurrentQueue.async {

        while true{
            print("hello")
            sleep(1)
        }

        while true{
            print("world")
            sleep(1)
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: You are writing about tasks (plural) but your code contains only **one** task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you've only given one work item to the queue to be performed. It loops forever printing "hello", then loops forever printing "world". Obviously, it'll never get around to printing "world".

If you want these two actions to occur concurrently, then you'll need to submit to separate work items:

```
let concurrentQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "test", attributes: .concurrent)

concurrentQueue.async {
    while true {
        print("hello")
        sleep(1)
    }
}

concurrentQueue.async {
    while true {
        print("world")
        sleep(1)
    }
}
```